# How to update WCF after deployment

Tags: wcf, deployment

Generally after added service reference client, we need to update the service reference to get the latest changes.

I created a service and hosted in production server. This is used by some client. After some time, i changed the service (by including new methods or modify some methods) and updated in the production server. So how these are updated in the client.

Again i update in development and host the updated client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are using the SOAP bindings in WCF.

It depends on the scope of the change you have made.

If you have just added new operations to an existing service this won't affect existing clients.

If your service operation expose complex types, then if you have only added new fields then most client serializers will raise events rather than throw exceptions when encountering unexpected fields, with the net result that the client should still be able to cleanly deserialise your XML.

You need to be aware however, that if you have modified existing operations, or modified or removed fields in your contract types you may have made a breaking change to your existing clients. This means that existing clients will need to be recompiled against your new service contract and then redeployed in order to continue to consume your service.

Comment: ok. So you are telling that if i give any new functionality and change existing functionality to the existing client,  we need to recompile the client application with the new servie and then reploy it.

Comment: No, I am saying it depends what changes you have made. If you tell me exactly what you have changed then I will be able to tell you if you need to recompile the client or not.

Comment: ok actually i not yet deployed my service. I am thinking how to handle after deployment. If i add a new method to the service how to publish. For service simply we can simply put the svc file. But for clients? Like that all cases any full article or scenarios and how to handle. Actually my service needs to be access in jquery and asp.net so can u guide for better approach also

Comment: If you add a service operation (method) then consumers of the existing service operations will not need to change. Re calling the service by JQuery just try it and if you get stuck post a new question. Please mark my answer as such if it helped you. Thanks

Comment: sorry for delay. I will try the scenario . One more question. In my development i add the service reference which is using development server wcf address. When i deploy to client how to change the reference? Eg: In my development my service link is http://computer1/myservice/service1.svc. After hosted in prdn the wcf link is http://prdnsvr/myservice/service1.svc. So how to update this in clients?

Comment: You just need to make the service endpoint address configurable. Either use the <endpoint/> configuration node in the WCF configuration model or just use System.Configuration in .net. It's up to you but obviously it's essential not to compile the address into the client code.